# Which version of the Microsoft Office Interopt dll should I be using

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I'm currently working on an excel add in in Visual Studio 2010.

The version of Excel on my computer is Excel 2013.

Which version of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference do I need to use if I want to be able to debug the program (at the moment it returns an error stating that I don't have the correct version of office installed)? The latest that I can seem to find is v14. From reading around I get the impression that I may need to get a more recent version of visual studio to do this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2013 corresponds to the version 15. VSTO detects which Office version to run using the interop version. So, I'd recommend referencing corresponding interop files. There is no need to look for a separate installer of interop files for Office 2013, you can just add a COM reference to Excel 2013 in Visual Studio. The required interop files will generated and added automatically.

Finally, you may find the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.